# Want to make Email open alert when customer click the email in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have a condition that want to implemnet in salesforce.

My sales teams wants that, Suppose If they send email with 1st template to 50 customers and some customers didn't open the email. But rest all customers who opens or clicks that email, another email with different template will send by sales team using slaesforce.

I have tried using google and used some links. Make a SandBox account, and stated to make workflow, but not understand properly.

I am biggner in Salesforce. So Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you guys not clear my above point then please follow example below:-

Suppose a mail is send to 10,000 customers. 200 customers open that email. so at that time, we again get only 200 customers (who open that email) email id and then again send different email to only that 200 customers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare HTML email template and send to the customers, when the customers open it, the HTML email status will be changed and # of tımes opened field set to 1 . You can also setup a workflow with email alert and trigger it if the # of tımes opened =1 , send second email